# How to have multiple user sync Mendeley Group with Overleaf group projects?

Tags: overleaf, mendeley

I collaborate on a project in Overleaf which is linked to a Mendeley group that all collaborators add their references to. However, I am the only one who is able to sync the Mendeley reference in Overleaf, so when someone else adds a reference to the group, it does not appear until I refresh it, as I am the one who connected the Mendeley group to Overleaf. Is there any way that anyone on the project can sync with Mendeley without having to wait for me to click refresh?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thanks @Zarko! I have been a silent consumer of TeX SE for quite some time, and now decided to ask my first question!

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ A workaround would be to export the .bib file from Mendeley Desktop and upload it to DropBox, or Google Drive, or any other cloud-storage services that would generate a URL to access the file. You can then add the .bib as a linked file to your Overleaf project using this URL. If you're interested in this idea, see https://www.overleaf.com/help/247 (under the heading "Linked File").